# Python: Why reading file in multiple parallel processes is slower than in 1 single process/thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

What could be the reason that Python multiprocessing is slower that a single thread while reading binary files?

```
def getBinaryData(procnum, filename, pointer_from, pointer_to):
    binary_values = []

    start = time.time()

    with open(filename, 'rb') as fileobject:
        # read file byte by byte
        fileobject.seek(pointer_from)
        data = fileobject.read(1)

        while data != b'' or pointer_position < pointer_to:
            #binary_values.append(ord(data))
            data = fileobject.read(1)
            pointer_position = fileobject.tell()
    end = time.time()
    print("proc ", procnum, " finished in: ", end - start)
    return binary_values

def worker(procnum, last_proc_num, file_path, bytes_chunk, return_dict):
    """worker function"""
    print(str(procnum) + " represent!")
    if procnum == 0:
        greyscale_data = getBinaryData(procnum, file_path, 0, bytes_chunk)
    elif procnum == last_proc_num:
        greyscale_data = getBinaryData(procnum, file_path, procnum * bytes_chunk, os.stat(file_path).st_size)
    else:
        greyscale_data = getBinaryData(procnum, file_path, procnum * bytes_chunk, (procnum+1) * bytes_chunk)

    size = get_size(len(greyscale_data))

    return_dict[procnum] = procnum


def main():
    cpu_cores = 10
    file_path = r"test_binary_file.exe"
    file_stats = os.stat(file_path)
    file_size = file_stats.st_size

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()
    jobs = []
    for i in range(cpu_cores):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i, cpu_cores-1, file_path, int(file_size/cpu_cores), return_dict))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
    print(return_dict.values())
```

While single-threaded process finishes to read 10mb file in ~30seconds - the multiprocesses solution gets it done way slower.

Python log output:

[10 processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDRcJ.png)

[1 process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAOGO.png)

Ruled-out issues:

- IO bottleneck (NVMe SSD)
- CPU/RAM bottleneck (16 cores, 4.4 GHz / 64GB 3200GHz RAM)

Comment: This looks like that the second process start when the first is ended ( and so on ). Every process need to allocate data to read file. in the 1 process is not needed.

Comment: an SSD can do over 100 MB/s so those 10 MB should be done in 0.1 seconds, 9.9 seconds are spent elsewhere, so you probably need to profile the code, this is clearly not a problem about reading files.

Comment: you are actually making Python calls to read the file 1 byte at a time.

There are few things that could be poorer performant than this - this code is so bad performance -wise that it would be really hard to start fixing it.

For one, since the 90's the lesser amount of data the S.O. can read from a file at once is 4K (4096) bytes or so - although the S.O. caches that, you are really making 4000+ function calls possibly crossing into the kernel, just for this stage.

Comment: 10MB canbe read in no time (ok, a few 10 miliseconds) in Python or any other language - if that is your final file size, just read all data into memory in each process. 

Otherwise, for really large files or 10s,100s of 10MB files, you can use a memory-mapped file shared across processes.

Comment: @jsbueno python also buffers files (about 8Kb of it at a time), so this doesn't really do that much of system calls, still reading files byte by byte is not python's thing, and more of a C thing.

Comment: yes - but the slowness here might come from various other sources. (there is also a .tell call for each byte). it might ultimately be caused by the S.O. somehow trying to optmise and share a buffer across processes, and having to do some context-switching for each of these calls.

Comment: @jsbueno

While debugging I got to the idea that it has to do with reading byte-by-byte in multiple processes simultaneously, however, I can not see the reason for independent processes to have problems with reading the same file and making operations on the byte level.

Answer (score -1):

Processes are heavy and it takes a lot of time to creates and ends a process so in my opinion reading the file is really fast but most of the time it takes to create and terminate the process.

To reads a lot of file it's enought to use multithreading because thread are light and GIL works like True multithreading for i/o operations.

It's recommended to use multiprocessing when you need to execute heavy operations.
[image]
Source of picture: https://youtu.be/kRy_UwUhBpo?t=763
He told that the img is from `fastpython.com`.

Comment: Processes are slow to create, but nowhere near slow enough to explain the timing difference here.

Comment: I wrote single app using multiprocessing and I performed tests on how the number of processes translates into increased performance.
- up to 4. processes performance increased significantly,
- up to 7 processes performance increased noticeably
- 8 or more processes - the efficiency decreased.

Why? Process != physical thread or core. the OS is responsible for allocating processor power to the processes and here is a problem.
You can try to set higher priority for your app or find faster lib written in c/cpp. In my case such lib was pandas - speeded up the running time from 30s to 8-9s.